# how to redirect websocket request through node js from reactjs to java server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket

I have a requirement like I need to fetch some job status which was running on a java server,
I will hit some API to start the job and the job has diff life cycles, which I need to fetch over the socket and show it on the react application, for this, I had open a connection in react js, so the java server is posting the status dynamically to frontend server whenever there is a change in lifecycle status by using WebSocket, but I am running react application with node, in this flow the react application is opened a connection and java server is reaching directly react application without node route, my question is there any way I can create WebSocket server in node and from there I can read the life cycle statuses

Comment: **Pro tip** for requirements like this it helps to draw a block diagram of what client talks to what server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. I assume you're talking about real [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) connections, not [socket.io](https://socket.io/) connections in my answer.  (Because that's what I know how to do. If you use socket.io, maybe someone else's answer will help you.)

A WebSocket (wss://example.com/sock/whatever) is an escalated https connection that becomes persistent, held open by

- the client
- the nginx reverse proxy server
- the java server.

You need to set up your Java server application to accept ws requests at a particular path. [A MDN writer explains this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_a_WebSocket_server_in_Java).  That Java server does not have to implement https, because the nginx reverse proxy server does that for you.

I think your requirement is to have your nodejs server application act as the websocket client, establishing a connection to your Java server application.  use [npm's ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#usage-examples) package in your nodejs code for that.

You'll configure nginx to serve as a reverse proxy.  It will accept your client's websocket connection requests and relay them to your Java server, while handling the https - to- http work for you.

Configuring nginx as a reverse proxy is a little fiddly. But here's a suggestion as a starting point.

```
events { # we can have many simultaneous ws connections
         worker_connections 768;
}
http {  # websocket reverse proxy settings /sock/whatever path
         map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
             default upgrade;
             '' close;
         }
         upstream websocketserver { # Java server app on Javahost listens on port 4000
             server javahost.example.com:4000;
         }
         upstream appserver { # nodejs server app on this host listens on 3000
             server 127.0.0.1:3000;
         }
         server {
             listen 443 default_server;
             server_name $hostname;
             ssl on;
             ssl_certificate  /etc/ssl/certs/whatever.pem;
             ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/whatever.pem;
             ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
             root /home/whatever/html;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             location /sock/ { # no proxy buffering for websockets!!!
                 proxy_pass http://websocketserver/sock/;               
                 proxy_buffering off;
             }
             location /app {
                  proxy_pass http://appserver/app;
                  proxy_cache_bypass 1;
             }
         }  ...
```

This projects, to the world, the illusion that your Java server and your nodejs server are on different paths on the same URL.

Production tip:  Sometimes websocket connections that have been established for hours or days shut down for no easily discerned reason. You would be wise to have your websocket client code respond to `close` and `error` events by logging something and trying to reconnect.